# Caffe does not make snapshots on SIGINT

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

When I'm pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in terminal, caffe stops training but does not make snapshots. How to fix it?
My solver:

```
net: "course-work/testing/model.prototxt"
test_iter: 200
test_interval: 500

base_lr: 0.001
momentum: 0.9
weight_decay: 0.005
lr_policy: "fixed"

display: 50
max_iter: 60000

snapshot: 5000
snapshot_format: HDF5
snapshot_prefix: "course-work/testing/by_solver_lr0"
snapshot_after_train: true

solver_mode: CPU
```

Bash script:

```
TOOLS=./build/tools
NET_DIR=course-work/testing

$TOOLS/caffe train \
    --solver=$NET_DIR/solver_lr0.prototxt 2>&1 | tee $NET_DIR/1.log
```

Comment: I had problems with snapshoting to HDF5, try snapshoting to BINARYPROTO instead.

Comment: @Shai It is weird, but when I directly send SIGINT via `kill -s SIGINT <proc_id>`, caffe makes snapshot. `CTRL+C` still does not work.

Comment: is it possible that due to the `tee` pipeline the signal from the keyboard is somehow directed to a different process?

Comment: @Shai Yes, you are right. `tee` was a problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Redirecting caffe's output through `tee` and pipes might alter the way the OS handles and transfers signals to processes. Try avoiding `| tee` to make sure `SIGINT` reaches caffe.

Note that [`caffe` tool](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/tools/caffe.cpp#L51-L56) has two flags

```
DEFINE_string(sigint_effect, "stop",
             "Optional; action to take when a SIGINT signal is received: "
              "snapshot, stop or none.");
DEFINE_string(sighup_effect, "snapshot",
             "Optional; action to take when a SIGHUP signal is received: "
             "snapshot, stop or none.");
```

These flags can help you define caffe's behavior on [SIGINT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#SIGINT) and [SIGHUP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#SIGHUP).

Comment: What's an alternate way to log the output?

Comment: @shaunakde I usually use `screen` and redirect to file in the foreground

Answer (score 1):

A good way to log caffe output is

```
GLOG_log_dir=/path/to/log/dir $CAFFE_ROOT/bin/caffe.bin train 
—solver=/path/to/solver.prototxt
```

This does live logging of caffe output and `SIGINT` definitely reaches caffe.

Comment: And how does this solve the problem? What **GLOG_log_dir** means?

Comment: Caffe uses Google Logging Library(GLOG) , GLOG_log_dir specifies the directory for the log files.